# old question reappearing after months

Tags: discussion, questions, request

From time to time old (about 2 months) questions reappear anew, the last author 
named then is "community". Is this a kind of routine? What is the idea behind?

Answer (score 7):

The system automatically bumps old questions which don't have any (upvoted?) answers, under the guise of the "Community" user, in order to expose them to fresh eyes. See [this MSO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6981/why-does-a-question-appear-as-modified-by-the-community-user) for more information.

Comment: it is our feeling that questions with no upvoted answers have not been sufficiently vetted by the community and could use some additional love.

Comment: At least the last occurence of that phenomen which made me ask here was a question with answers. This leads to another question: why are so many questions with anwers among the questions listed ba "unanswered"?

Answer (score 2):

It is worth checking out [the "Community" user page](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), BTW.

There you will learn that this is a automated process that takes care a various little jobs and "owns" all the needs an owner but should be be attributed to a real user.

Community exist on all the sites in the Stack Exchange network.